# How do you create a bracket tournement sheet on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, brackets

I am trying to create a bracket sheet that automatically moves a teams name to the next cell
example:

Team 1 in cell 'a1', Team 2 in cell 'a2'

The score for each team in cell:

'b1' for Team 1, 'b2' for Team 2

I would like the team name to automatically move to the next cell if the score is greater... Example:

team 1 score 5 and team 2 score 3 then team 1 will automaticall move into cell 'd1'

-or-

team 2 score more then team 2 will move automatically in cell 'd1'

Comment: I don't think this question should be on hold. It's pretty clear what he's looking for (cell D1 is A1 if B1>B2, or cell D1 is A2 if B1<B2), and Engineer Toast successfully answered it below. What's the confusion?

Comment: If you look at the edit mode of the question, it's especially clear. He just doesn't understand the StackExchange markup syntax. I'll clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are neater ways to do this but I'm on mobile right now and can't play in Excel. Here's an option that will work for the example you gave.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B1),ISBLANK(B2)),"",IF(B1>B2,A1,IF(B2>B1,A2,"ERR")))
```